# Moving data from multible tables which are connected by Primary- and Foreignkeys

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm making an online budget with mssql as my database. When creating a user i have 4 tables which are connected with id's and foreignkey id's.

How can they be moved to 4 new tables and change id's and the FK_ID's change accordingly?

I haven't had any ideas or success in my research, so i came here.

The tables look like this:

```
Category
ID | Name
1     A

Type
ID | Name | FK_CatID
10     B        1

Group
ID | Name | FK_TypeID
2      C       10

Unit
ID | Name | FK_GroupID
3     D        2
```

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? What have you tried already? Did you read [ask]?

Comment: You are doing a database normalization, so far so good, but looks like you should also create the relationships. Consider editing your question and adding the relevant database related information (tables structure, database used)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Database in MSSQL Server Right click on the database which contains the tables then select Tasks then "Generate Scripts" then on "choose objects" then choose "select specific database objects". Here you select the tables you want. Afterwards click the advanced option. 
[image]
 You need then to Script Schema and Data and choose ok 
[image]
 then next. You may choose to save the script on a new window. In the script you need to rename the Primary and Foreign Keys. When you are satisfied with the renaming then execute and see if it produces your requirements. Hope this helps.

Comment: From the original question, how do you get to the OP using MS SQL Server?

Comment: I had looked on the question tags.

Comment: The `sql` question tag is too broad, it could be many rdbms... oracle, mysql, sqlserver and many more.

Comment: Gnyasha, when the program is done it will not be hosted on my own server and they don't allow for that, but thanks.